# Do I have to rebuild a branch if I switch to this branch from other branch in a workspace?

Tags: git, eclipse

guys:

I am new to eclipse and Git. I wonder if I have to rebuild a branch if I switch to this branch from other branch in a workspace. Can anyone give me a good URL to learn the concept?

Thanks a lot

Sam

Comment: Normally, eclipse should be able to realize that you switched and rebuild the necessary parts appropriately (that's what JIT is for, right?).... but you know how IDEs can get confused sometimes.... so, if you see something funky after switching, it might be necessary to rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please correct me if I am wrong. If I switch to a new branch and build it, will eclipse lose the war of the old branch?

Comment: @eftshift0 JIT is something Java VMs do. What you mean is that the Eclipse compiler for Java (ecj) compiles incrementally (only the changed files).

Comment: Actually, you are right.... the follow-up is kind-of a subset of the main question. I stand corrected. i don't know the answer to that one, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch a branch and *Project > Build Automatically* is enabled, Eclipse runs the **incremental project builders** for the files that have changed ([read more about this concept in the Eclipse help](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_builders.htm)). So, if the project builder supports incremental building, only the changed files will be built.

In case of Java, the Eclipse compiler for Java (ecj) incrementally compiles the changed `.java` files to `.class` files. But if you also have a Maven or Gradle build file to e.g. generate JARs or WARs, this has to be done manually by default via a launch configuration; it is not done automatically via a project builder.

In the comments you ask also whether in Git files will be lost by switching a branch. If you have uncommitted files that do not exist in the target branch, they will be kept; if they exist in the target branch but differ, you can choose what to do: commit, stash, reset (the only option where the changes will be lost) or cancel switching the branch.